# Quering data using linq C# MVC4

Tags: c#, database, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I have two tables one card and the other one registereddatatime. The first table keeps the data of the cards, and the second keep the data of the card date and time when has been scanned.

So I Have a list of all the cards and when I click in the cards i want to get the time and date when the card has been scanned.

So in the controller I have the action result like this :

```
public class CardController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ICardDataSource _db;
        public  CardController(ICardDataSource db)
        {
            _db = db;
        }

public ActionResult details(int id)
        {


            var model = _db.Cards.Single(c => c.CardId == id);;


            return View(model);
        }
```

And in the index view I use the following html helper:

```
<ul>

    @foreach (var card in Model)
    {
        <li>@Html.ActionLink(card.Description, "details", "Card", new { card.CardId} , null);</li>
    }

    </ul>
```

and in the detail view I want to show the registered data for every card. When I load it says that null reference is sent instead of int32.

Detail View :

```
@model Card.Manager.Models.Card

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "detail";
}

<h2>Detail</h2>

@foreach (var e in Model.RegistrationDTs)
{
    @e.RegistrationDateTime
}
```

Comment: Could you provide what you have for the details view?

Comment: Can you show us the index code to go with the index view?  Right now I only see the details code.

Comment: I added the detail view

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bad variable name in link. The parameter name you have in your controller action `int id` needs to be the same name you pass when you construct the link.

```
@Html.ActionLink(card.Description, "details", "Card", new { id = card.CardId } , null);
```

Comment: hmm isnt it the same as mine?

Comment: No it has new { id = card.CardId } You have to tell what paramater correlates with the ones inside your method!

Comment: I get this message: The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult details(Int32)' in 'Card.Manager.Controllers.CardController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
Parameter name: parameters

Comment: When you create an anonymous object with `new { }` if you don't specify the name of the properties you're trying to define, they'll take on whatever name the variables you assign to them had. In this case you were sending CardId to the server and since the ASP.NET MVC model binder works off the name, nothing was getting bound to the variable `id` which is what you were expecting to get server-side.